# Finite measure spaces with a total closed set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Endowing $R$ with a finite borel measure. How to find a closed set with its total measure and every closed subset of it has minor measure?

Comment: This closed set is called the "support" of the measure.

Comment: It is interesting that in a non-Lindelof space, it could happen that there is no such set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal O:=\{O\subset \Bbb R, m(O)=0, O\mbox{ open}\}$ and $S':=\bigcup_{O\in\mathcal O}O$. $S'$ is open hence separable, and by Lindelöf property we can extract a countable subcover, which proves that $S'$ is open and of measure $0$. Let $S:=\Bbb R\setminus S'$ (support of $m$). It has full measure.

Let $F\subset S$ a closed subset and assume that $m(S)=m(F)$. We have $S'=S^c\subset F^c$ and since $m$ is finite, $m(F^c)=m(S^c)=0$. So $F^c\in\mathcal O$ and $F^c\subset S'$ which gives $S\subset F$. So if a closed subset of $S$ has full measure it should be $S$.

---

Note that it works for a [Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) topological space, since it's the only feature of the real line we have used.

Comment: Why is $S'$ open?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I should have writtent that $\mathcal O$ is the collection of _open_ subsets of measure $0$. I will fix it, thanks!